# How to create Cassandra primary key in correct way

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.persons (
    id uuid,
    country text,
    city text,
    address text,
    phone_number text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, country, address)
);
```

My main scenario is to get person by id. But sometimes I want to get all cities inside country and all persons inside city as well.

I know that Cassandra must have at least one partition key and zero or more clustering keys, but I don't understand how to organize it to work most effectively (and generally work).

Can anybody give me advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to be able to query by both `id` and `country`.  Typically in Cassandra, the way to build your data models is a "one table == one query" approach.  In that case, you would have two tables, just keyed differently:

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.persons_by_id (
    id uuid,
    country text,
    city text,
    address text,
    phone_number text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

TBH, you don't really to cluster on `country` and `address`, unless a person can have multiple addresses.  But a single PK is a completely legit approach.

For the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.persons_by_country (
    id uuid,
    country text,
    city text,
    address text,
    phone_number text,
    PRIMARY KEY (country,city,id));
```

This will allow you to query by `country`, with persons grouped/sorted by `city` and sorted by `id`.  In theory, you could also serve the query by `id` approach here, as long as you also had the `country` and `city`.  But that might not be possible in your scenario.

Duplicating data in Cassandra (NoSQL) to help queries perform better is ok.  The trick becomes keeping the tables in-sync, but you can use the `BATCH` functionality to apply writes to both tables atomically.

In case you haven't already, you might benefit from DataStax's (free) course on data modeling - [Data Modeling with Apache Cassandra and DataStax Enterprise](https://academy.datastax.com/#/online-courses/ca2e1209-510b-44a6-97de-d5219d835319).

Comment: So, does this mean that I need to create three tables: the first one for querying by person_id, the second for cities by country and the last for persons by city? And when I save a new person, I need to save it into three tables simultaneously?

Comment: @Alexey Yes, that is correct.  Although, if you know which country the city is in at query-time, you might be able to get away with just two.